# Acento de insistência ou enfático

Tags: ortografia, fonemas, sintaxe, acentuação

Para expressar sentimentos fortes de emoção, alegria, raiva ou por outra razão qualquer o falante pode emitir uma sílaba tônica com duração e intensidade fora do normal. Existem também situações onde a primeira sílaba é destacada.

> Exemplos:
>
> Está muuuuito quente hoje!
>   Goooool. 
>   Deve existir mais **ex**portação e menos **im**portação.

Até que ponto é interessante utilizar esse destaque na escrita de textos não formais?

Existem regras para uso desse recurso?

Comment: "iminente" e "eminente" são homófonas (ambas lidas /i/), esse exemplo não funciona.

Comment: não confunda o sentido de iminente com eminente.

Comment: 1. A sílaba tónica de `Olhaaa` é a primeira, não a segunda; mas a segunda é que está prolongada. Foi acidental? 2. `Existem também situações onde a primeira sílaba é destacada.` - o exemplo dado não é um de destaque da primeira sílaba, é um de destaque da sílaba controversa; ser a primeira é só coincidência.

Comment: Agradeço pelas sugestões... Editei a pergunta fazendo as correções.

Comment: @Artefacto O dicionário da Academia e a [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/eminente) indicam *eminente* pronunciado /emiˈnẽt(ə)/.

Comment: @Jacinto Eh... O dicionário da Academia é famoso por ter transcrições fonéticas duvidosas (como "geração" com "e" mudo, não marcar dissimilações exceto nos casos mais óbvios como em "príncipe" e por aí adiante). A norma da pronúncia de "e"s iniciais em Portugal é que são lidos /i/ exceto se a sílaba for "ex"/"es"/tónica e casos em que a vogal é nasal como "encontrar" (onde mesmo assim se ouve também com /ĩ/ ou algo no meio). /emiˈnẽt(ə)/ parece-me pronúnica pseudo-culta.

Comment: Iminente e eminente são pronunciadas bem diferente pelo que eu saiba. Ocorre pronúncia igual quando a pessoa não sabe o que cada palavra significa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [Moderna Gramática Portuguesa de Evanildo Bchara](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kA5LywXfV-kC&pg=PT87&lpg=PT87&dq=acento%20de%20insist%C3%AAncia&source=bl&ots=E5o7adJcwB&sig=PO3BxqQCA0byR_Jmntx9mqq_eLI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCGoVChMI_ZSlq7qFyQIVzOsUCh3a1gTP#v=onepage&q=acento%20de%20insist%C3%AAncia&f=false) apresenta uma boa discussão com exemplos do acento de insistência. Este consiste em pronunciar uma sílaba com intensidade, altura e/ou duração superior ao normal. Pode recair na sílaba tónica ou noutra, mais comummente na primeira. É um fenómeno muito comum na linguagem oral. Pode exprimir uma emoção:

> *Ele é um **ban**dido*.
> *Está com**ple**tamente destruído!*
> *Fan**tás**tico, Melga! Fan**tás**tico Mike!*

Pode também ser um acento de insistência intelectual, visando chamar a atenção para alguma coisa, especialmente em palavras derivadas por prefixação:

> *Falamos de verbos **in**transitivos.*

Quando a indicar este acento na linguagem escrita, o autor é soberano. Bechara diz que alguns escritores fazem-no com a repetição da vogal da sílaba sobre qual recai o acento. Neste [outro livro](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_xRyirTXCWMC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=acento%20de%20insist%C3%AAncia&source=bl&ots=iY8kdPTgpe&sig=kp-VrTh7KomfE0hQMcmnEyovyNk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFMQ6AEwB2oVChMI_ZSlq7qFyQIVzOsUCh3a1gTP#v=onepage&q=acento%20de%20insist%C3%AAncia&f=false) encontramos exemplos com indicação da fonte, não só da repetição da vogal, como também da consoante:

> *[R]rrolar* ([Guimarães Rosa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guimar%C3%A3es_Rosa), [*Saragana*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagarana), 1946.)
>
> Se pudéssemos, nós que temos experiência da vida, abrir os olhos dessas mariposinhas tontas... Mas é inútil. Encasqueta-se-lhes na cabeça que o amor, o *amoor, o amooor* é tudo na vida, e adeus.  ([Monteiro Lobato](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monteiro_Lobato), [Cidades Mortas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cidades_Mortas), 1919.)

Evanildo Bechara, na sua gramática, indica o acento de insistência intelectual com negrito itálico. Portanto cada autor adopta o artifício que mais lhe agrada e que melhor se adequa ao caso concreto. Eu consigo ouvir o ***R*** a rolar na palavra *rrrolar*; já em *fantástico*, conseguimos prolongar o **A** mas não o **T**.