# Como é que um falante pode fazer a distinção entre «imigrante» e «emigrante»?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia, preposições, homofonia, antónimos

*Imigrante* e *emigrante* são palavras opostas que são muito fáceis de confundir, visto que cada imigrante é um emigrante, e cada emigrante um imigrante. Ouvi que têm a mesma pronúncia (pelo menos em Portugal?), quer dizer que o ‹e› inicial em *emigrante* se pronuncia como /i/. Então na língua oral, como é possível fazer a distinção, de forma eficiente, entre as duas palavras?

Por exemplo, posso utilizar *para* e *de* para isso?

> Ele é emigrante **da** França *(porque agora vive fora)*
>
> Ela é imigrante **para** a Alemanha *(porque não é alemã)*

Ou posso conseguir isso com uma pronúncia exagerada? Por exemplo "êêmigránte"/"éémigránte" e "íímigránte"? Se for, seria melhor usar /ê/ ou /é/?

Comment: Parece-me aceitável, quando se quer realçar que é *emigrante* e não *imigrante*, exagerar a pronúncia com  acento de insistência intelectual  na primeira sílaba [(vê esta pergunta)](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/acento-de-insist%C3%AAncia-ou-enf%C3%A1tico) e alterando a pronúncia do ***e*** inicial para /e/.

Comment: Quando dizes "ouvi que que têm a mesma pronúncia" queres dizer que ouvistes falantes pronunciarem **e**migrante como **i**migrante? Soa bem estranha esta troca, já que o "e" em início de palavras nào costuma ser falado como "i". Pense em outras palavras que iniciem com as mesmas sílabas, tais como _emitir_, _Emília_ (nome próprio) ou _emirado_. Seria bastante estranho (e nunca as ouvi assim) que elas fossem pronunciadas como _imitir_, _imília_ e _imirado_.

Comment: @gmauch estranho que te pareça, é assim que essas palavras são pronunciadas

Comment: @gmauch talvez seja uma diferença transatlântica. Pelo menos no Norte de Portugal, soa (mais ou menos) como "imitir", "imília" e "imirado".

Comment: @ANeves, teu comentário faz sentido. Acho que cabe ao OP nos esclarecer o contexo onde ouviu esta troca do E por I. Caso ele confirme que isto ocorreu em Portugal, sugiro adicionar a tag "portugal" à questão.

Comment: @gmauch sim, parece-me que era português do Portugal. Não o mencionei porque não sabia que tem esta diferença. Editado. Como é que se pronuncia o "e" inicial de *emigrante* no Brasil? /é/ ou /ê/?

Comment: @DanGetz, a pronúncia das vogais _e_ e _o_ varia de acordo com a região do falante no Brasil. Aqui no Sul elas são normalmente pronunciadas fechadas _ê_ e _ô_. No Nordeste são pronunciadas abertas _é_ e _ó_. Não tenho certeza quanto a pronúncia em outras regiões.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As palavras são de facto homófonas (pelo menos na língua padrão); a ambiguidade ou se desfaz pelo contexto, ou, permanecendo, poderá não alterar significativamente o sentido da frase (porque como dizes é apenas uma questão de perspectiva). Por exemplo, uma frase como:

> Os imigrantes são um grande problema.

é ambígua; mas geralmente não surgirá isolada:

> Os imigrantes têm chegado aos milhões nos últimos meses; são um grande problema.

*Emigrante de/da França* e *imigrante para a Alemanha* não se usam muito.

Para designar o país de origem, em vez de *emigrante da França*, diz-se geralmente *emigrante francês* (mas também se ouve *um emigrante da Jamaica*, por exemplo).

Para designar o país de destino, usa-se mais a preposição *em*. Por exemplo: *um emigrante açoriano no Canadá* (mas: *o açoriano emigrou para o Canadá*).

Em todo o caso, quer *emigrante*, quer *imigrante* designam uma migração de um local para outro; adjuntos introduzidos por *de* e *para* não esclareceriam nada a respeito da escolha entre as duas palavras, porque não dão informação sobre o país usado como referência.

Comment: Não gosto desses exemplos. Alguém pode "estar emigrado cá", e alguém pode "estar imigrado em". A complexidade extra da frase parece trazer mais informação, mas na verdade não a traz... porque se pode também dizer as frases opostas: «ele está imigrado em França»; e «ele está emigrado cá na Alemanha.» Ou estou a perceber isto mal?

Comment: @ANeves sim, parece-me que tens razão. Editei a resposta.

Comment: As palavras não são homónimas, quando muito seriam homófonas, sendo que nesse caso seria mais uma questão do sotaque do que grafia/leitura.

Comment: @Joum Obrigado pela correção.